# How to resolve this issue? Keyword not supported: 'metadata'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I hit link then error on it that Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.

This is my connectionstring:

```
<add name="demoDB" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.database1.csdl|res://*/Models.database1.ssdl|res://*/Models.database1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=demo.database.windows.net; initial catalog=*******; User Id=*****; Password=******; Integrated Security=True; Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

This is code for download data:

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["demoDB"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM Section_B"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is user code:

```
using (var context = new Models.demoDB())
        {
            bool isValid = context.Users.Any(u => u.Username == _user.Username && u.Password == _user.Password);
            if (isValid)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(_user.Username, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "MasterPage");
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password");
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Your connection string is specific for Entity Framework. For "plain SqlServer", see https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will fix your issue

Change it as:

```
<add name="demoDB" connectionString="Data 
Source=demo.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=*******; 
User ID=*****;Password=******" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: When I change connection to which you suggest above then there is error Keyword not supported: 'data source'.

Comment: I have edited my question area please see this again

Comment: @UsmanAzam.have you tried the above connectionstring in your webconfig

Comment: when I remove metadata then showing error that keyword not supported: 'data source' and if I add metadata then error showing keyword not supported: 'metadata'

Comment: @UsmanAzam,just copy paste the above connectionstring and then try..and let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205575/discussion-between-ishwar-gagare-and-usman-azam).

Comment: Internet connection was lost while chatting with you